# OAuthTokenCredential Inactivity

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I developed a web platform that allows our customers (More than one), to receive payments, using PayPal REST API.

Under development everything runs well, but in production, after some time of inactivity, looks like the required Authentication Token needs to be regenerated.

To handle multiple customers I'm using a synchronized HashMap when the key is a composition between the customer_id and the payment_method_id and the value is a POJO, containing the token and a creation date.

The token is the current OAuthTokenCredential, generated by the following code:

```
Properties p = new Properties();

// Evaluate the right endpoint
if (STATUS_ACTIVE) {
    p.put("service.EndPoint", "https://api.paypal.com");
}
else {
    p.put("service.EndPoint", "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com");
}

p.put("clientID", clientId);
p.put("clientSecret", clientSecret);
p.put("http.ConnectionTimeOut", "5000");
p.put("http.Retry", "1");
p.put("http.ReadTimeOut", "30000");
p.put("http.MaxConnection", "100");
p.put("http.UseProxy", "false");

Payment.initConfig(p);

OAuthTokenCredential tokenGen = new OAuthTokenCredential(
    clientId,
    clientSecret
);
```

**The issue is that the user cannot buy, so it is a bug that I need to solve fast.**

The message I receive from paypal is the following:

```
Error Code 401 with response : Server returned HTTP response code 401 for url https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment
```

Do you know if there are some timeouts on the OAuthTokenCredential Validity?
I tested the code using junit, so, the token is generated and cached rightly.

Now I have a 5' (300 Seconds) token timeout. Is there a best practice on doing this things? Is there something I wrong?

Thanks a lot, Davide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the PayPal-issued access tokens will expire after a certain time, see [How PayPal uses OAuth 2.0](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/paypal-oauth2/#access-token-validity-and-expiration). The validity duration is returned with the access token request as the parameter `expires_in` (in seconds):

```js
{
  "scope": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* ...",
  "access_token": "...",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "app_id": "...",
  "expires_in": 28800
}
```

Typical access token lifetimes are 8 hours for PayPal's Sandbox environment (as above) and 15 minutes for Live environment. You can contact PayPal's Technical Support if your implementation requires a longer token lifetime.

The Java REST SDK's `OAuthTokenCredential` class [exposes a method `expiresIn()`](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-java/blob/6704273cf5573e8219d9ed8cb9cc4722f0d0b083/src/main/java/com/paypal/core/rest/OAuthTokenCredential.java#L150-L158), which can be used to check the remaining validity duration: a value `<= 0` indicates an expired token and could be used for checking the current token's validity before making a request (you should probably use some buffer when using this approach).
Alternatively you can check for a 401 response status and trigger re-fetching the token if necessary – you should always make sure that your implementation handles this case.